# Recover wrong char between 2 strings

Tags: java, string, equality

I have 2 String : str1 & str2
They are nearly identical.

> str1 = 001
>
> str2 = 101

As you can see above, if I compare str1 with str2, '1' is the wrong char.
I would like to replace this char with an other : 'X'

> str1 = 001
>
> str2 = X01

this is my method which returns a String and has 2 string arguments (str1 & str2) :

```
    char charArray1[] = str1.toCharArray();
    char charArray2[] = str2.toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    
    for(int i=0; i<charArray1.length; i++){
        if(charArray1[i] != charArray2[i]){
            charArray2[i]='X';
        }       
    str = new String(charArray2);
    }
    System.out.print(str1 + " is now : " + str + "\n");
    return str;
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work. Indeed, I can't modify the wrong char '1' of str2 (I want X01 and not 101).. Do you know why?

Comment: `String`s are immutable in java (see their javadoc).  The `toCharArray` method can also be viewed, and can be seen (at least in the implementation I'm using, I suspect all...) to build a _new_ array.  This means that modifying this directly has no impact on the underlying array which the `String` is backed by.

Comment: So, if I understand, I should create a new char Array to create a new String ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should take the line `str = new String(charArray2);` outside the for loop because it doesn't make sense to initialize it for every iteration

Comment: @Bigote What is not working. Your code seems to work atleast on my system

Comment: Now it is working... I think my arguments was wrong! Thk ;)

Comment: This output `"001 is now : X01"` as it is. So this is working properly. I vote to close because of a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
    String str1 = "001";
    String str2 = "101";
    char charArray1[] = str1.toCharArray();
    char charArray2[] = str2.toCharArray();
    String str = "";

    for(int i=0; i<charArray1.length; i++){
        if(charArray1[i] != charArray2[i])
        {
            charArray2[i] = 'X';
        }       else
    str = new String(charArray2);
    }
    System.out.print(str1 + " is now : " + str + "\n");
```

Comment: Just to understand, if they are equal, why would I need to replace it, because it already have that character, isn't it ?

Comment: you are right.... it should work without th else part

Comment: wht o u mean with: I can't modify a char

Comment: I don't see the need for this solution, as explained, if `a == b`, there is no need to set `a = b`... so the `else` clause is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`str` should be allocated once when all is done.

There is no need to create a char array for both strings...

```
char charArray1[] = str1.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i<charArray1.length; i++) {
    if (charArray1[i] != str2.get(i)) {
        charArray1[i] = 'X';
    }
}
String str = new String(charArray1);
System.out.println(str1 + " is now : " + str);
```